# Websockets on shared hosting: not possible because of shared hosting itself or because of non-php integrations?

Tags: php, websocket

I want to run a basic chat application on my shared hosting.
I would use a PHP Websockets implementation library, [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

However, when I go to my shared hosting (Hostgator) websockets information page, it stated:

> PHP Socket Support?
>   If you are connecting out, it should work. We do not allow clients to bind to local ports for incoming.

What does it mean? Can I create my own websocket running the command via ssh? I would use this basic code in order to run it.

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8081
);

$server->run();
```

I noticed there were similar questions but most of the answers were saying it's not possible because the questioner was trying to use Node.js or Python websockets libraries, which are not supported on most of the shared hosting.

Comment: Shared hosting will not allow you to open up ports for listening. You have to have proper access for that.

Comment: Basically, support of web-sockets is a feature which some hostings support and some do not, so if they state so, you have to get another hosting/plan (may be VPS)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Main answer

Shared hosting will generally allow you to listen on a high port, e.g. the one you are using. However, there will be a number of problems in practice.

Firstly, the web server will probably only allow 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) inbound, so a port of 8081 would be blocked by the firewall. Your PHP listener would attach to the port, but would wait patiently for traffic that never comes.

Secondly, some shared hosts will have a load balancer in front of them, and they might only be configured to forward HTTP traffic. Since Web Sockets are a different protocol, they won't be set up to forward that. The same problem with ports is repeated here too - non-standard ports won't be forwarded.

To solve these problems, you need your own web server, where you can open ports (and set up load balancers) in whatever way you like. This is pretty cheap to do these days - for the price of a couple of cafe coffees per month, you can rent a small virtual server. It won't have as much RAM as a shared server, but it will be a lot more flexible.

### Design issues

I would draw attention also to using non-standard ports for Web Sockets to service a web application on standard 80/443 ports. This is not always a good idea. The non-standard ports will work fine on desktops and standard home internet connections, but for some office or mobile internet connections, you might get into a pickle.

It is better to put a load balancer in front of your app and then let it route traffic (Web Socket or HTTP) based on the protocol signature. This will allow you to use multiple protocols per port. If you are interested in exploring this, I recommend Traefik with Docker containers - I have set this up and it works very well indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the thourough explanation :). So, could be Pusher considered a sort of load balancer in your opinion? I noticed performances are much better using their service than hosting my own websocket server on my app (server)

Comment: @Enrico: Pusher is likely to have load balancers, yes, and they will probably be regionalised throughout the world, so users will send web sockets to the region with the lowest latency. Building on a service of that kind comes with its pros and cons - it can be faster to get to market, but then it makes you dependent on a service that might not be good value for money if you need to scale up.

Comment: Much clearer now...one last (newbie) question: if I deploy in production the websocket server through my application, for example via Laravel, do I need to manually log into the ssh console and start the server (in case of Laravel you do it through a php artisan websocket:serve command). If yes, then the server will be running until I turn it off manually again?

Comment: @Enrico, it depends entirely on how you set up your server. A good way to ensure the WS listener always starts up is to run it in Supervisor (or some other process watcher). If you use Docker/Traefik then either a Docker or Docker Compose restart policy.

Comment: thanks. sound like Docker is speeding the process a lot. I'll give it a try.