# How to fix this: Ajax request on a page cause to browser get slower untill it won't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dashboard page that send many ajax requests (about 100reqs) to show realtime results from mysql database. These requests are repetetive and goes on every few minutes (each request has a different timeout). At the begining it was every second ajax request and it goes to get lower in few minutes so didn't send any requtest after few minutes (stock on loading ajax request and none reaults came up) I changed it to minutes but still after few hours I have the same problem.

I need these requests and I deleted many unnecessary to get here. I also used `cashe: false` in ajax request. Is there anywhere else that browser save ajax request that it make it slower? if there is, how can I remove this memory or even use it to prevent send another ajax request!

So, my main question is this: How can I optimize these request to get results as fast as possible and never see the browser get slower? (I searched a lot and it is going to make me mad, I don't know any other solution, so if you had a solution about realtime results from database I will will thank you for sharing it)

(notice: after a few hours if I close browser and reopen it, the speed of requests get reset. It means I have to restart browser after hours and this is not acceptable in this project)

[a little about requests]:
these request are in `post` and `get` method both. This is one of them:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'funcs/mini_ajax.php',       
        data: dataStr,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            $(resultslabel).html(data);
        }
    });
```

If anything needed to help you give me a better answer please feel free to ask.

**Edit1**: These requests are in different loops that is defined in js by this function:

```
setInterval(function(){
    check_price('somevalue','someothervalue')
}, 3100);
```

Comment: Ajax is not the appropriate technology for what you're trying to do. Use websockets instead

Comment: This going to take some time to change all of requests. I will try this solution and update my question by results.

Comment: With ajax, something to consider is that (as given in the question) each ajax call will have its own success callback, which will be redefined and added to the heap on each firing of the setInterval(s). A define-once-use-many strategy would ensure that one copy of each callback needs to exist, thus GC will have less to do.

Comment: Taking this one stage further, maybe you could be even more economical by having a small collection of callbacks and include in the parameter passed to them data to control the precise behaviour. Of course, the heap may still grow for other reasons but this strategy would eliminate "callback growth".

Comment: `$(resultslabel).html(data);` suggests an inefficient data strategy by which `data` includes HTML markup. Consider returning actual data and reusing existing DOM structure(s).

Comment: I think that both ideas would be equally applicable to @ADyson's websocket idea.

Comment: As updating this question and sharing the recent results, After I learned how to use websockets in php (I never used it before) I want to tell you I think it is not possible (for now) because we are running on a shared host, they won't let ports listening open. Is there anyway to use websockets in shared hosts? Do you know any common port that is always open in shared hosts?

Comment: I found it! about the port and shared hosts, this answer works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964583/websockets-on-shared-hosting-not-possible-because-of-shared-hosting-itself-or-b .